# Decide which member function to call by ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++17, conditional-operator

If I want to call function `foo` on an object `thisThing` (in C# jargon, this is called the "receiver", so I'll call it that here too) and pass the argument `myStuff`, I'll do it like this:
`thisThing.foo(myStuff);`
Super simple, nothing surprising going on here.

If I want to change the argument to `yourStuff` if a bool value `b` is false, I'll do it like this:
`thisThing.foo(b ? myStuff : yourStuff);`
Also very simple, basic use of the ternary operator.

If I want to change the receiver to `otherThing` if `b` is false, I'll do it like this:
`(b ? thisThing : otherThing).foo(myStuff);`
A little bit weirder, you probably don't do this super often, but it's nothing crazy either.

But if I want to change the called function to `bar` if `b` is false, how do I do that?
I would think something like this:
`thisThing.(b ? foo : bar)(myStuff);`
But of course, this does not work.

Is there a simple, neat-looking, performant way of doing this, preferrably without redundantly specifying anything?
There will probably have to be some compromises made, but the point is to not have to repeat the receiver and arguments. So the following works:

```
if (b)
{
    thisThing.foo(myStuff);
}
else
{
    thisThing.bar(myStuff);
}
```

But you have to repeat the receiver and arguments. Imagine that `thisThing` and `myStuff` are placeholders for much more complex expressions. You might want to put those in local variables first, but that has implications for copying, and it does not play nicely if you have many arguments.

You might be able to take function pointers to those member functions and then do something like `(b ? pointerToFoo : pointerToBar)(myStuff);`, but dealing with function pointers tends to be messy (think function overloading) and it does not seem like something that the compiler would properly optimize away. But I'd be happy to be proven wrong here.

Comment: Is this bool known at compile time or run time?

Comment: "_You might want to put those in local variables first, but that has implications for copying_": You can simply make the variables references.

Comment: `thisThing.(b ? foo(myStuff) : bar(myStuff));`

Comment: @RichardCritten he doesn't want to repeat `myStuff` (as far as I understood)

Comment: @RichardCritten That's not going to work.

Comment: @NathanOliver In my case at runtime.

Comment: @RichardCritten Can you give more context to your example? I can't get this to work.

Comment: @NikoO with RichardCritten's solution you need to repeat the `myStuff` the same way as with the `if (b) ...else...` solution, but it's wrong anyway. I think he meant `(b ? thisThing.foo(myStuff) : thisThing.bar(myStuff))` but its just as pointless

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know, but I'd like to see how Richard got their code to work anyways.

Comment: @NikoO it just doesn't work at all, he probably just typed the comment without thinking too much (yes, that happened to me too more than once in the past).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use member function pointers, but you need special syntax to call the function via the pointer:

```
struct X {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

int main() {
    X thisThing;
    bool b = false;
    (thisThing.*(b ? &X::foo : &X::bar))();
}
```

However, I would not recommend to actually use it like this (unless there are reasons not shown in the question). Note that it won't work like this when `foo` or `bar` are overloaded.

Anyhow, in my opinion also your other examples are not good use-cases for the conditional operator. The conditional operator is not just a equivalent replacement for if-else. It has slightly different use-cases. Sometimes one uses the conditional operator to determine the common type of two expressions. Sometimes you cannot use an if-else. For example when initializing a reference:

```
 int& x = a ? c : d;   // cannot be done with if/else
```

My advice is: Don't use the conditional operator to save on typing compared to an if-else. The difference between if-else and the conditional operator is almost never the amount of code you have to write only.

Comment: This also cannot be used with overloaded functions or functions mismatching in types.

Comment: "*This also cannot be used with overloaded functions*" - Yes, it can.  You just need to explicitly tell the compiler which overload you want to use, by type-casting to the desired overload's signature, or using a local variable of the correct function pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
thisThing.foo_or_bar(b, myStuff);
```

and:

```
ThingClass::foo_or_bar(bool b, SomeType myStuff)
{
  if (b)
    foo(myStuff);
  else
    bar(myStuff);
}
```

Comment: [Some people would strongly argue against using bool arguments to alter the method's behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior).

Comment: @meagar true, but IMO the original pattern the OP suggests is pretty uggly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to **@463035818_is_not_a_number**'s answer, but rather than using the pointer to member operator(`.*`) and all the parentheses, I would use `std::invoke` instead:

```cpp
struct X {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

int main() {
    X thisThing;
    bool b = false;
    std::invoke(b ? &X::foo : &X::bar, thisThing);
}
```

However, just like the original answer, this cannot be used if function overloads were included.

Comment: "*this cannot be used if function overloads were included*" - Yes, it can.  You just need to explicitly tell the compiler which overload you want to use, by type-casting to the desired overload's signature, or using a local variable of the correct function pointer type.